# Highcharts rendering high amount of data points showing message "A webpage is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do?" in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts in React and am having performance issues in Firefox 60.0.

It initially renders an empty chart fine, but whenever I try to update it with data, it gives me the message "A web page is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do?"

The web app will always be displaying anywhere from 20k points to 100k points, sometimes millions depending on the filters the user selects.

I have tried most optimizations [Highcharts recommended](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#optimize-performance). This is my code to initialize the chart:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let myChart = Highcharts.chart('my-plot', {
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'xy',
      marginTop: 40
    },
    boost: {
      useGPUTranslations: true,
      usePreAllocated: true
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          this.onZoom(event);
        }.bind(this)
      }
    }
    yAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      reversed: true,
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
          this.onZoom(event);
        }.bind(this)
      }
    }
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        turboThreshold: 0,
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function(event) {
            this.onLegendClick(event);
          }.bind(this);
        },
        stickyTracking: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        snap: 0
      }
    },
    series: [[]]
  });

  this.setState({myPlot: myChart});
}
```

And I am updating the data using:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevProps.plotData !== this.props.plotData) {
    let chart = this.state.myPlot;

    while(chart.series.length) {
      chart.series[0].remove(false);
    }

    chart.redraw();
    this.props.plotData.forEach((series) => {
      chart.addSeries(series, false);
    }
    chart.redraw();
  }
}
```

Here is the gist of what I am trying in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmwoy4pzx).

I tried setting the redraw boolean to false when adding the series in hopes that it will not freeze up so often, and did a chart.redraw() after the forEach so it will redraw altogether at the very end. That was in another SO or blog post to help reduce lag, which did help in shortening the amount of times that "this web page is slowing down the browser" message appeared. But I'd like that message to go away completely.

This doesn't happen when I used other charting libraries like Plotly. But I like highcharts and the flexibility it offers, so I would like to continue using it.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in online code editors like codesandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: I unfortunately can't reproduce the error. I installed version 60.0 and ran it in a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmwoy4pzx) but I don't see that message appear. It does freeze for a second though.

Comment: I noticed that you have the boost module initialized in the wrong way. Check it now: https://codesandbox.io/s/o5z98km486

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. It's very smooth now. That message still shows up in my app, but at least I can eliminate boost and maybe even highcharts as being the bottleneck. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Can I change this comment to the answer and you will mark it as a correct one?

Comment: Yes please do add it as an answer so I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boost module has to be initialized properly:

```
// import Boost module
import Boost from "highcharts/modules/boost";

// initialize it
Boost(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/o5z98km486